# rails drop down menu association without db table ....

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, associations, rails-activerecord

Respected ppl ...

i have these models :

```
class SanctionedPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :hospital_id, :sanctioned_posts, :designation_id

  column :district_id
  belongs_to:designation
  belongs_to:hospital
  belongs_to:district
  belongs_to:division
end

class Hospital < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible  :beds, :fax_no, :hospital_name, :phone_no, :district_id, :institution_type_id, :location_id, :division_id, :block_id, :hospital_type_id, :IsAdministrativeLocation, :IsTribal, :latitude, :longitude

  belongs_to:district
  belongs_to:division
  belongs_to:block
  has_many:sanctioned_posts

end

class Division < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :division_name, :state_id

  has_many:health_dept_locations
  belongs_to:state
  has_many:districts
  has_many:hospitals

  has_many:sanctioned_posts

  validates_associated :districts
end
```

I want to be able to create dropdowns in my sanctioned_posts for such that divisions narrows down the districts which narrows down the blocks which narrows down to hospitals ... 
(so that i dont have to select from a million hospitals ...) ...

I have tried everything from http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus-revised and http://railscasts.com/episodes/193-tableless-model still to no avail ...

====================================

im using simple form ... and this allowed me to accomplish a similar task for the hospitals create form ...

```
<%= f.association :division,label_method: :division_name, value_method: :id, include_blank: false%>

  <%= f.input :district_id do %>
      <%= f.grouped_collection_select :district_id, Division.order(:division_name), :districts, :division_name, :id, :district_name, include_blank: true, label: 'District'  %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.input :block_id do %>
      <%= f.grouped_collection_select :block_id, District.order(:district_name), :blocks, :district_name, :id, :block_name, include_blank: true, label: 'Block' %>
  <% end %>
```

(+ the accompanying coffeescript... )

But in my current scenario im not able to do the same ...since im not storing division,district,block id in the sanctioned_posts model .... but i believe the hospital_id would be somewhat helpful in this context ....

Thnx very much in advance :) ...

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Why not use CoffeeScript and JQuery to do REST requests on the index method and you can configure your routes accordingly?
Example: States have schools, schools have students

States have_many schools, schools have_many students

Select first state of Illinois. Illinois has ID of 11

get request to /states/11/schools.json

```
SchoolsController < ApplicationController
  responds_to :json

  def index
    states = State.find(params[:id})
    respond_with states.schools
  end
end
```